# How to pre-populate check box on jsp

Tags: java, javascript, dojo

I want to pre populate check boxes on jsp. I have following code on my `Mycheckbox.jsp`

**Code**

```
MyDTO [] dtoArr = Context.getParameter("PREFdtoSettings");
<%=dtoArr.length%> is 6;

dtoArr[i].getId(); gives me the unique ID;
```

In above code am setting `PREFdtoSettings` parameter in request context in handler class

There are almost `100 checkboxes` on the page as shown in the code

```
CheckBox No.1
`<input type=”checkbox” id=”dtoArr[i].getid()”> FXX </input>`
```

Similarly, I am having 100 checkbox which has unique id and that id information am getting by `id=”dtoArr[i].getid()”.`

Now, I want to `pre populate` the 6 checkboxes by matching `dtoArr[i].getid()` among `100` existing `checkboxes` on the `pageload` but I am not sure how I can achieve this.

I was going through some blogs and it suggested that I should create `JSON Object` of `dtoArr` and use my `JSON` in my `javascript DOJO` but I am not sure how can I implement it.

Any suggestions or input would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: a short question, `<input type=”checkbox” id=”dtoArr[i].getid()”> FXX </input>` is what rendered HTML? dtorArr[i].getid() is the unique id?

Comment: <input type=”checkbox” id=”dtoArr[i].getid()”> FXX </input> is  HTML, and dtoArr[i].getid() is used to dynamically giving Unique ID. yes.

Comment: and what u mean by "want to pre populate." you mean changing the html attribute?

Comment: @Rachel if viewing the html source, there will be something like <input type=”checkbox” id=”uid1”> FXX </input> <input type=”checkbox” id=”uid2”> FXX </input> ... right?

Comment: If that is your HTML, then it's incorrect.  You can't just use javascript to generate an ID on the fly.  If that's JSP, then it's incorrect as well.  You need to put that as an el expression (wrap it in `${...}`) to have it evaluated when processing.  And then you'd still need to use an el factory that allows message calls (jboss el, for instance).

Comment: @ jebberwocky, you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is not 100% clear, but to prepopulate checkboxes on a JSP side, don't use a client-side method.

Set the value when rendering.

```
<input 
    type="checkbox" 
    id="${dtoArr[i].getid()}" 
    value="${dtoArr[i].getValue()}" 
    checked="${dtoArr[i].checked?'checked':''}"> 
  FXX </input>
```

This is, assuming that you're using an el factory that allows for method calls.  Otherwise it's the same principle, but a bit uglier.